# Error when configuring Hudson EC2 Plugin

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, hudson

I want to run Hudson on EC2 and use [Hudson's EC2 plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) to create Hudson slaves to run my tests.

I installed it, but when trying to configure it, I get a lot of errors:

[image]

What's going on? How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you manually confirmed the keys actually work? Maybe you should post the full stack trace?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I can't actually see the errors mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Our working platform:
2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:34:28 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
this is on a AMI thats an M1.Xlarge in US-E-1C.

I suggest that you either rollback your hudson version to 1.387 (if on 1.395) OR
update your maven plugin to 1.395.

We are running Page generated: Mar 16, 2011 3:16:10 PMHudson ver. 1.395 with these
[image]plugin versions:

Backup Plugin
Backup plugin allows archiving and restoring your Hudson home directory.
1.6 1.4.1

CVS Plugin
This bundled plugin integrates Jenkins with CVS version control system.
1.3  (1.2)

Email-ext plugin
This plugin allows you to configure every aspect of email notifications. You can customize when an email is sent, who should receive it, and what the email says.
Warning: This plugin is built for Hudson 1.397 or newer. It may or may not work in your Hudson.
2.12    2.5

Git Plugin
This plugin allows use of GIT as a build SCM. Git 1.3.3 or newer is required.
1.1.6   0.8.3

Github Plugin
This plugin creates links from Jenkins to Github projects.
0.4 0.2

Green Balls
Changes Hudson to use green balls instead of blue for successful builds
1.10    1.6

Maven 2 Project Plugin
Hudson's Maven 2 project type
Warning: This plugin is built for Hudson 1.401 or newer. It may or may not work in your Hudson.
1.401    (1.395)

Phing Plugin
This plugin allows you to use Phing to build PHP projects.
0.7 0.4

Promoted Builds Plugin
This plugin allows you to distinguish good builds from bad builds by introducing the notion of 'promotion'.
Warning: This plugin is built for Hudson 1.399 or newer. It may or may not work in your Hudson.
2.0 1.7

Subversion Plugin
This plugin adds the Subversion support (via SVNKit) to Hudson.
1.23     (1.20)

xUnit Plugin
This plugin makes it possible to publish the results of an execution of a testing tool in Hudson.
Warning: This plugin is built for Hudson 1.399 or newer. It may or may not work in your Hudson.
1.16.1  0.6.1